# Laravel Redis Caching

Tags: performance, caching, laravel-5, redis

I'm now working on a big project,we decided to use redis as cache in our system so,when we put some data in the cache and then the original data is changed,how could we know ? and what is the best practice in this case ? to delete the old data and replace the new one ? Is there any mechanism to replace just the changed part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to keep in mind for caching for a large application using redis :

1) localise your cache as much as you can. For example if you have 5 information for every user that needs to be cached. Instead of accessing them all together make simple cache for each info.

2) choose the right data structure. Use redis' set, hash, sorted set and bit operations wherever possible.

3) make sure your system will work even if redis is not available (to overcome downtime). That is, check in redis if it's there serve, if not get from dB and populate in cache. So that even If redis is not available you will get values from DB

To answer your question, You can do it in three ways

1) you can maintain cache alongside your DB. During on success of transaction in the DB update the cache. So that you will not loose any information. But implementing this is bit difficult

2) whenever a transaction begins drop cache belongs to that. So that the values in the cache will be removed and will be fetched from DB during the successive read request.

3) maintain a last accessed or created time in both cache and DB. During every read compare them and decide. This is the most reliable solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will try that and tell you what will happen.